# Why futures are not cached in session 1st level cache?

Tags: c#, hibernate, caching, nhibernate, future

I have "static" readonly entities which I simply load with `QueryOver<T>().List<T>()`. All their properties are not "lazy". So some of them have N+1 problem.

I tried to use `Future` to avoid N+1. But it looks like then NH considers entity properties as "lazy". And when I access them it even reloads entities from db one by one (leading to the same N+1 situation) despite that all entities were preloaded preliminary and should be cached in the session 1st level cache. Here is the code how I'm doing it:

```
        var futures = new List<IEnumerable>();
        futures.Add(s.QueryOver<DailyBonus>().Future<DailyBonus>());
        futures.Add(s.QueryOver<DailyBonusChestContent>().Future<DailyBonusChestContent>());
        // ... other entities ...

        // all queries should be sent with first enumeration
        // but I want to ensure everything is loaded 
        // before using lazy properties
        foreach (IEnumerable future in futures)
        {
            if (future.Cast<object>().Any(x => false)) break;
        }
        // now everything should be in cache, right?
        // so I can travel the whole graph without accessing db?
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, futures); // wow, N+1 here!
```

I checked this behavior using hibernatingrhinos profiler.

So what is going on wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only correct way of using futures for loading entity with collections is with `Fetch` which means joins for each query:

```
  var q = session.Query<User>().Where(x => x.Id == id);

    var lst = new List<IEnumerable>
    {
        q.FetchMany(x => x.Characters).ToFuture(),
        q.Fetch(x=>x.UpdateableData).ToFuture(),
        session.QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Fetch(x=>x.Characters).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.Characters.First().SmartChallengeTrackers).Eager
            .Future()
    };

    var r = session.QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .Future();

    foreach (IEnumerable el in lst)
    {
        foreach (object o in el)
        {

        }
    }

    return r.ToArray();
```

It's still better than join everything in a one query - NHibernate won't have to parse thousands of rows introduced by join x join x join x join...

You can add normal select queries (without `Fetch`) to to the same batch but they won't be used for retrieving collections on another entity.